# pygame Android not reading file

Tags: android, pygame

I have written a game in pygame and porting this to Android, using pygame subset for Android.
My game uses python file module ( read and write both). But in Android I am not able to read file in Android. Is any thing I missing here!!!

```
import pygame

try:
    import android
except ImportError:
    android = None

def main():
    pygame.init()
    if android:
        android.init()
    print "reading file content"
    file_read = open("text.txt","a+")
    print file_read # This prints file object in andorid
    for line in file_read:
    print "line",line
    print "reading file done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    a+  Opens a file for both appending and reading. The file pointer is at
 the end of the file if the file exists. The file opens in the append mode.
 If the file does not exist, it creates a new file for reading and writing.
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

I was opening file in a+ mode where, file pointer is at the end. This is the reason I was not able to read file content.

Strangely its works in windows :(